# adding css link to masterpage

Tags: master-page

I have a css script that I want to add to my masterpage, I was wondering how I would do this.
I have tried `<SharePoint:CssLink Name="site" runat="server" />`

and `<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="site" runat="server" />`
but these don't seem to work or not find my file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This post](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Refer-Scripts-and-CSS-Style-Sheet-in-SharePoint-2013-Visual-Web-Part-and-Master-Page.aspx) describes common cases. In you case you should use something like this

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" Name="/_layouts/15/SFS.Ashok.Refer/Styles/site-visualwp.css" runat="server" After="corev15.css" />
```